# Using Viewshed Analysis in ArcGIS Desktop to Find Points Where Entire Area is Covered?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, arcgis-pro, viewshed

I have a DEM of an entire state and I would like to do a viewshed analysis. But instead of me using existing points to determine the viewshed, I would like to find all points where the entire state would be covered by a viewshed.

So for example, I want to find suitable locations for antenna placements. Instead of me just guessing trying to figure out which location would give me the best results, I would like the GIS to optimally find points where the entire state would be covered with antenna coverage.

I have access to all tools/extensions in ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro.

Is doing something like this possible?

Comment: I cant really answer this, but thought I would comment. Viewshed and Observer Point Analysis require a point dataset input. This is used to determine the height from which the analysis is undertaken. A starting point for your assessment would be to potentially identify the high points / ridge lines in your study area (how large is it). then use these areas to initiate the investigation into suitable sites and start narrowing down the criteria.

Comment: Yeah I know it would require a point dataset. I was just thinking of something that would generate the point dataset for me. Like find the fewest number of points it would take to get 100% “viewability.” I imagine doing something like that would be pretty computationally expensive though.

Comment: There isn't an "out the box" solution in ArcMap. I am not sure how big your state is, and how large your raster DEM is. but an option would be to create a fishnet over the study area. Run the "Add Surface Information" Tool using the "Z_MAX" option. Then rank these maximum elevation values or classify them into zones and use that to stat ID'ing the initial areas for investigation of the viewshed. There is a lot more that gos into the viewshed and visibility (aspect, height, location etc)...this could at least be a start.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this question because it can prove useful to whoever is going to read this thread in the future. As someone already commented on, there is no "out of the box" solution in ArcGIS. BUT, there is indeed a viable option using a QGIS' plugin called "Visibility analysis" [LINK](https://landscapearchaeology.org/qgis-visibility-analysis-manual/).

The interested reader may want to focus on the "total viewshed" as described in that link. The total viewshed would express the inherent visibility of the landscape, indicating which parts of an area are the most visible.

It has to be borne in mind that the analysis is a computer-intensive one.